# Creating a Calendar Heatmap for number of events that occured at a time/day of week in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large time-series dataset where one of the variables is the date and time of an event saved as a factor.  I want to create a matrix heatmap with the x-axis showing the day of the week and the y-axis showing the time of day so we can see how many events occur on a particular.

I have been able to use `plotCalendarHeatmap` from the Time Projection `r` package to create a frequency heat map based on day and month for the time series. But I was unable to plot something approximating a day of the week vs/ time of day scenario.

Here is some sample code similar to what is found in my dataset:

```
x <- c(1:18)
y <- factor(c("6/28/2013 7:23", "9/8/2013 17:59", "9/24/2013 10:46", "10/20/2013 18:05", "9/11/2013 17:36", "9/14/2013 23:27", "12/28/2013 6:48", "7/20/2013 17:26", "8/26/2013 7:51", "9/14/2013 9:12", "10/9/2013 22:01", "9/27/2013 16:52", "8/25/2013 8:22", "9/14/2013 23:26", "9/22/2013 18:29", "8/26/2013 21:57", "8/10/2013 13:53", "8/11/2013 17:25"))
data <- data.frame(x,y)
colnames(data) <- c("ID", "starttime")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
# generate more illustrative dataset: you have this already
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:1000
y <- as.POSIXct("06/01/2013",format="%m/%d/%Y")+sample(0:(210*24*60)*60,1000)
y <- strftime(y,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
data <- data.frame(ID=x,Starttime=y)

# you start here...
library(lubridate)     # for wday(...)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)  # for brewer.pal(...)

data$date <- as.POSIXct(data$Starttime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
data$dow  <- wday(data$date)
data$cdow <- wday(data$date,label=T)
data$tod  <- as.numeric(data$date - as.POSIXct(strftime(data$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")))/60
data$bins <- cut(data$tod,breaks=1:24,labels=F)
counts    <- aggregate(ID~bins+dow,data,length)
colnames(counts)[ncol(counts)] <- "Events"

ggplot(counts, aes(x=bins,y=8-dow))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Events))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"),
                       breaks=seq(0,max(counts$Events),by=2))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=7:1,labels=c("Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat"))+
  labs(x="Time of Day (hours)", y="Day of Week")+
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: I can run it fine with your illustrative data.  However, when I put mine in, I seem to get poor calculations on the `data$tod  <- as.numeric(data$date - as.POSIXct(strftime(data$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")))/60` line.  Here is the first lines of my `head` after following your code: 
    > head(data)
      ID       Starttime                date dow  cdow  tod bins
    1  1 6/27/2013 23:05 2013-06-27 23:05:00   5 Thurs 1385   NA
    2  2 6/27/2013 23:06 2013-06-27 23:06:00   5 Thurs 1386   NA

Comment: Remove the division by 60. It looks like your data returns a time difference in hours (not minutes), so there's no need for conversion.

Comment: it turns out my data is in seconds.  So I just divided by 3600 instead